# Why store data in XML over individual columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Just short question on using XML in a SQL Server database...

I have a new table that stores some data taken from another table, and have been informed I must store this data in XML into a column rather than just storing the values in their own columns.

For the life of me, I can work out why this is better and I've asked several others whom can't see the benefit either. At no point will the XML be used as XML anywhere in code, only the data striped out from it will be used.

Wondering if anyone has any opinions, for or against, to help me understand a little better.

Many thanks for you thoughts,
P

Comment: Well, you (1) might receive the XML from e.g. a web service and want to store it for future reference, or (2) you might need to store some "flexible" and potentially "hierachical" data in a convenient fashion .....

Comment: Who informed you? What are their reasons?

Comment: What Curt said. There are reasons to do this, and there are plenty of reasons not to. The answer to this question depends entirely on your situation.

Comment: It's valid to store data in XML if there's a valid reason, otherwise it adds extra time/code in having to parse the data back out of it. I'd be asking whoever told you: "WHY?"

Comment: You get a big performance boost from parsing the XML into tables and working with them - but if performance isn't a problem and you want the flexibility of having a copy of the original document, you might want to consider the XML column. It's entirely subjective

Comment: I asked and was told "I think its better", I'll be bring it up again shortly, just want some community ammo with me when I do.

Comment: There isn't any real valid reason that I see to story it, as I mentioned its never going to be used as XML anywhere. The XML is created in a proc and a proc will read back out the XML from the row, but only return the values from it that I need.

Comment: @LiveToFlu: `XML` makes sense if you need the data to be portable between different platforms, different physical layers, and/or between different organizations, etc. From what I've heard of your situation, it doesn't sound like a good fit for your organization's needs.

Comment: Similar question here that might prove interesting reading for you:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/54685/when-should-i-use-the-xml-data-type-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Using the XML datatype is performance consuming. Indexes are tricky. Updating part of a document is really difficult compared to a SQL update. The cost should not be underestimated.

Maybe the 'person who told you' heard about 'NoSql/Xml databases being better'. The answer, of course, is that it really depends on the context. And one could argue that SqlServer used with XML columns is not NoSql.

Maybe you should ask these questions :

- do you just need to store the hierarchy ? ( a nvarchar(max) column would then be enough )
- do you also need to query the hierarchy ? (then XML or relational, depending on schema complexity)
- is it difficult to model the hierarchy with relational schema ?
- will the hierarchy change over time ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, XML type is used when data structure is volatile . Even though you can validate data in XML column with xml schema, the most work is done on application side. For example, if you receive data from third party services, it's hard to guarantee it will always follow the same format and have the same attributes.

Comment: Thanks a1ex07, I completely understand what your saying, but in my case all I'm _basically_ doing is getting **col1** and  **col2** from **tableA** and creating
`<xml><col1>value1<\col1><col2>value2<\col2><\xml>` and then storing that in **tableB**. So its never coming from anywhere else and that is how it will always be generated.

Then the XML will be read back out, getting value1 and value2 from it to be passed back up to the running code, and that's its, twill be used for nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't understand the requirements given to you by the people who commissioned the project and are paying for it, how can we?

It's possible that there's a reason for the requirement that you haven't told us about because you didn't know about it.

And it's possible that there isn't.

There's no way for anyone on this forum to know.

Answer (score 0):

Solution has been reworked and we're going to store the values in columns rather than XML. Unclear requirements to being with and a lack of a complete vision of what was/will be needed by all parties!

Thank you all for your replies.